# Changing & Adding items in checkout_index_index.xml

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, totals, order-totals

I'm trying to customize Order Summary in the sidebar.
[image]

The module that I'm currently working on will modify the final total price and I need to display the additional price under `Shipping`.

I've taken a look into [Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml) and it seems like the totals are defined in the layout starting from line 365. Following [this guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html), I've tried to insert a new child for `totals`. I've given the component a JavaScript file and in that file I've also linked my .HTML theme. I'm basically following how it's done in `Magento_Checkout`. Unfortunately, this did not work.

To see if I'm doing something wrong, I tried changing the title of one of the `<item>`'s. For example, in [Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/shipping.html](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/shipping.html), if I understand correctly, line 10 takes the title that's given in line 374 of `checkout_index_index.xml` layout file. However, after overriding it with my module's `checkout_index_index.xml` there's no change, so there's likely I'm doing something wrong.

Would appreciate your help!

**Edit 1:**

I've tried the solution posted below. In fact it was quite similar to what I had initially but it still doesn't do the job. I feel like I'd better share what I have currently:

1. `checkout_index_index.xml` (I'm also overriding one other component but that works without problems)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/style.css" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/setupfee</item>
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/checkout/cart/summary/setupfee</item>
                                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. I have originally had a single .js file but I followed the answer given below so:

`js/view/checkout/cart/summary/setupfee.js`

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
],
function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
    "use strict";
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed: window.checkoutConfig.isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed || false,
            template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/cart/summary/setupfee'
        },
        totals: quote.getTotals(),
        isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,
        isDisplayed: function() {
            return this.isFullMode();
        },
        getRawSetupFee: function() {
            var price = 0;
            if (this.totals()) {
                price = totals.getSegment('fee').value;
            }
            return price;
        },
        getValue: function() {
            var price = 0;
            if (this.totals()) {
                price = totals.getSegment('fee').value;
            }
            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        },
        getBaseValue: function() {
            var price = 0;
            if (this.totals()) {
                price = totals.getSegment('fee').value;
            }
            return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getBasePriceFormat());
        }
    });
});
```

`js/view/checkout/cart/totals/setupfee.js`

```
define(
[
    'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/cart/summary/setupfee'
],
function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({

        /**
         * @override
         */
        isDisplayed: function () {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

3. `template/checkout/cart/summary/setupfee.html`

```
<!-- ko -->

  <tr class="totals setup-fee excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="text: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
            <span class="price"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>   

<!-- /ko -->
```

As far as I can tell, all my files are in correct directories. I don't really care much about what's going on in .js files with the pricing and everything. For now I just want to make sure that this new `<item>` works and is displayed in Order Summary. The rest I believe that I will be able to handle on my own. I'm just stuck here :s

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `NameSpace_YourModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                       <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">NameSpace_YourModule/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/setupfee</item>
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                 <item name="template" xsi:type="string">NameSpace_YourModule/checkout/cart/totals/setupfee</item>
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Setup/Design Fee</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And now you will need three files:

`1. NameSpace_YourModule/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/setupfee.js`

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define(
    [
        'NameSpace_YourModule/js/view/checkout/summary/setupfee'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @override
             */
            isDisplayed: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

`2. NameSpace_YourModule/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/cart/summary/setupfee.js`

```
/*global alert*/
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed: window.checkoutConfig.isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed || false,
                template: 'NameSpace_YourModule/js/view/checkout/summary/setupfee'
            },
            totals: quote.getTotals(),
            isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,
            isDisplayed: function() {
                return this.isFullMode();
            },
            getRawSetupFee: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = totals.getSegment('fee').value;
                }
                return price;
            },
            getValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = totals.getSegment('fee').value;
                }
                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            },
            getBaseValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = totals.getSegment('fee').value;
                }
                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getBasePriceFormat());
            }
        });
    }
);
```

`3. NameSpace_YourModule/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/setupfee.html`

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko -->

  <tr class="totals setup-fee excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="text: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
            <span class="price"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>   

<!-- /ko -->
```

**To show it in cart page**

`4. Add this in NameSpace_YourModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="setup_fee" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">NameSpace_YourModule/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/setupfee</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                         <item name="template" xsi:type="string">NameSpace_YourModule/checkout/cart/totals/setupfee</item>
                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Setup/Design Fee</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

`5. NameSpace_YourModule/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/setupfee.html`

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko -->
<tr class="totals setup-fee excl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work still. I've edited my original post, showing what I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into my `checkout_index_index.xml` I realized an obvious mistake of mine. I missed the following in my code:

```
<item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
```

Watch out while coding tired folks!